# How to limit parsing and display the previously parsed contents in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, parsing

I am new to iPhone development. I am parsing a URL and displayed its content in the table. On clicking a row it plays a video. When I click a done button, I once again call the tableview.

When I call the table view it parses the URL once again to display the contents. I want to limit the parsing for 1 time and for the next time I want to display the contents which are parsed at the first time. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to sound condescending, but, don't do that?  When the results are first requested, parse them and store the parsed results.  From there on out, only return those.

Without more information about your problem, it seems that trivial.